# In 2d CFT, if the partition function is $Z=\text{Tr}q^{L_0-c/24}$, where is the analogue of temperature?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, conformal-field-theory, partition-function

In 2d CFT, restricting to the holomorphic part of the theory, the torus partition function is given by
$$Z(q)=\text{Tr}q^{L_0-c/24}$$
where $L_0$ is the element of the Virasoro algebra, i.e. mode of energy-momentum tensor, $c$ is the central charge, and the trace is over the Hilbert space in radial quantization.

This is analogous to the partition function in the statistical mechanics
$$Z(q)=\text{Tr}e^{-\beta H}$$
where $\beta=1/T$ and $H$ is the Hamiltonian.

I can see that the $L_0$ is can be associated with the Hamiltonian in the statistical mechanics. However, what does the temperature (i.e. $\beta$) in statistical mechanics correspond to in the 2d CFT?

Should I think of it as a partition function with external thermal bath that sets temperature fixed?

Comment: The $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$ insert the analogue of $\beta=\frac{1}{T}$ as well as a "twisting" parameter since $\tau$ is a complex number.

Comment: Exactly, the temperature is part of $\tau$. Also, keep in mind that most theories don't holomorphically factorize.

Comment: @Nogueira Thank you for your answer. I understand that $\tau$ is $\beta$ here. Do you mean twisting by 'multiplied by $i$'? Or do you mean 'complex temperature'?

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you. So the inverse temperature is the complex structure, i.e. magnitude of momentum (or distance in momentum space) is temperature? Also, I am thinking about four-dimensional theories. (More specifically, 4d $\mathcal{N}=2 chiral algebras constructed by Beem, Rastelli, et.al.) Except the even dimensions, what other information can we immediately use to determine criteria of holomorphic factorization?

Comment: @Nugi $\tau$ is the modular parameter of the torus. The torus basically compute the partition function of the CFT in a $S^{1}$, where the "size" of the torus is the inverse of the temperature. The modular parameter is complex is because we can also twist the $S^{1}$ along the torus, i.e. rotate the $S^{1}$ by acting with the generator $L_0-\overline L_0$.

Comment: @Nogueira And that twisting of $L_0-\bar{L}_0$ should change $\tau$ (and $\bar{\tau}$ to consider non-holomorphic part too) nontrivially, but leave the torus partition function invariant, right? And, what does $L_0-\bar{L}_0$ do exactly to $\tau$? I know that $L_0+\bar{L}_0$ is scaling, i.e. $\tau\rightarrow \lambda \tau$ although I'm not sure what $\lambda$ should be. Does it mean scaling by $\lambda$ in $\tau$ and $\lambda^{-1}$ in $\bar{\tau}$?

Comment: It sounds like this is veering into a separate question. But the thing about $L_0 \pm \bar{L}_0$ is just that they accompany the real and imaginary parts of $\tau$ when you expand $q^{L_0 - c/24} \bar{q}^{\bar{L}_0 - c/24}$.

Comment: Regarding chiral algebras, these are holomorphic by definition so $\mathrm{Tr}(q^{L_0 - c/24})$ is the full partition function (but not a modular invariant one). Its main use is computing the superconformal index but there could be some benefit of a traditional stat-mech interpretation that I haven't heard of yet.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I understand the $+$ which is consistent with time evolution in radial quantization. Perhaps for $-$ I should actually expand the terms and collect them. And yes, I think it is going into a separate discussion too. But at the moment, I can't think of any other option. If it seems like the discussion diverts again in this comment, perhaps that's the signal. Regarding the chiral algebra, perhaps we 'can' think of it as stat-mech interpretation in the usual 2d cft sense, though the operators should be cohomology classes. Can I hear your opinion?

Comment: The simplest way to couple a $1 + 1$ dimensional theory to a bath only gives $+$ because the thermal circle on which you compactify is orthogonal to space. However, in order for this to be a Euclidean CFT on a torus, the partition function needs to be modular invariant. The vacuum character of a chiral algebra has more complicated modular properties but according to https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.07679 there's still a lot you can do with them.